# How to create data between two different dates with limited data

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create the data between two different dates.

Data in table looks like as shown below:

```
StartDate  | EndDate       | StudId      | Active
-----------+---------------+-------------+-----------
01-01-2009 | 02-15-2009    |    12345    |       Y  
02-16-2009 | 03-15-2009    |    12345    |       Y  
03-16-2009 | 04-10-2009    |    12345    |       N  
04-11-2009 | 05-31-2009    |    12345    |       Y  
01-01-2009 | 02-15-2009    |    23642    |       Y  
02-16-2009 | 03-15-2009    |    23642    |       Y  
03-16-2009 | 04-10-2009    |    23642    |       N   
04-11-2009 | 05-31-2009    |    23642    |       Y
```

and the data in table goes on  with different Startdate, EndDate and StudID.

I am trying to get the result as shown below:

```
Startdate   |  StudID  | Active
------------+----------+--------
01-01-2009  |  12345   |    Y
01-02-2009  |  12345   |    Y
01-03-2009  |  12345   |    Y
01-04-2009  |  12345   |    Y
  .               .         .
  .               .         .
02-15-2009  |  12345   |    Y
02-16-2009  |  12345   |    Y
```

As shown above I am trying to load the active data for student based on dates between Startdate and enddate.

We don't have any daily data using startdate and enddate we need to create daily data.  If there is a gap between EndDate and next Startdate then the Active field should be '0' for those dates

Can someone suggest how to do this?

Comment: And....what did you try? Do you use any of the known SQL Server date functions? Do you use a Case statement, IIF logic? Help us or just delete the question because SO is not a help desk.

Comment: I tried case statement which returns data for the field Active for the Startdate, and tried to create dateranges between startdate and enddate and used as cross join to this table. I haven't tried If logic, I will try if logic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This requires `calendar` table and `join`

```
WITH calendar
     AS (SELECT Min(StartDate) AS dates,
                Max(EndDate)   ed_date
         FROM   Yourtable
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(dd, 1, dates),
                ed_date
         FROM   calendar
         WHERE  dates < ed_date)
SELECT a.dates as Startdate,b.StudID,b.Active
FROM   calendar a
       JOIN Yourtable b
         ON a.dates BETWEEN b.StartDate AND b.EndDate
ORDER  BY dates
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

**Note:** I have used `Recursive CTE` to generate dates. It is better to create physical calendar table and use it in queries like this

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/VQSA4013)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
declare @tmp date;
select @tmp = max(EndDate) from tmpTable;
print @tmp
;with cte as
(
select min(StartDate) over() as dd from tmpTable
union all select dateadd(day,1,dd) from cte where dd < @tmp
)

select distinct dd as StartDate, isnull(Studid, 12345), isnull(Active,0) as Active from tmpTable as t 
right join cte as c on c.dd between t.startDate and t.enddate  
where t.Studid = 12345 or t.studid is null
option (maxrecursion 0)
```